# Double authentication cross browser support

Tags: authentication

I have the typical Sharepoint 2013 setup with a sharepoint.domain.com as the primary web application and a my.sharepoint.domain.com application for the user my sites.  I'd like to have the users be able to authenticate to one and be authenticated on the other without having the see the same windows authentication screen twice.  All the solutions point to using IE but most of my users are primarily chrome / safari users.  How can I set up my environment so that users only have to authenticate once to the server?